# debuggerproxy.dll missing -- but where do I install it?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

So, I'm getting this not-so-rare error from what I have been able to search around for solutions:

Activation context generation failed for "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\WDExpress.exe". Dependent Assembly debuggerproxy.dll,processorArchitecture="X86",type="win32",version="1.0.0.0" could not be found. Please use sxstrace.exe for detailed diagnosis.

I get this btw when I try to start up my VS 2013 Express Win Desktop version.

I went into Computer->Manage->Win Logs->Apps and see a file called debuggerproxy.dll is missing. Well, I downloaded the file and copied into this location:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\WDExpress

but it didn't help.

Does anyone know where this file should be copied to?

Thanks...

Comment: You can't do an installation repair/reinstall? These kinds of things are not usually solved easily by trying to recreate an installation by copying files around.

Comment: If your installation is bjorked, uninstall/reinstall.